# Can't find my authentication key anywhere

Tags: azure

On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-how-to-signup#authentication-key it says:

*Authentication key
When you sign up for Translator, you get a personalized access key unique to your subscription. This key is required on each call to the Translator.
Retrieve your authentication key by first selecting the appropriate subscription.
Select Keys in the Resource Management section of your subscription's details.
Copy either of the keys listed for your subscription*

There is no Resource Management section when I click my subscription.
There is no Keys section when I click my subscription.

There is no Keys section when I search https://portal.azure.com/#home

So where is my authentication key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already signed up for Translator then you can retrieve your authentication key by first selecting the appropriate subscription, select Keys in the Resource Management section of your subscription's details and then copy either of the keys listed for your subscription.

Comment: The thing is, there is no Resource Management section in my subscription details.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking under Resource Groups. Under those Resource Groups however, you still need to creare the actual Resources. When you click them, then you can find your keys.